# Return to the homepage and move to the section

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

the links on the homepage navbar is an easy scroll when click on it it moves the page the the section with id, but i need the user when they are on any other page not the homepage and click on any links on the navbar, it return back to the homepage and move to the section.

This code doesn't work for me.

```
<a href="/index.html#how-we-work">How we Work</a>
```

Comment: When you click on this link, what happen ?

Comment: Does the `<section>` have the `id` `how-we-work`?

Comment: doesnt make anything, you can look into this website that im developing evisax.com/tracking.html and click on the how we work link.

Comment: @swellar in the homepage all the section have ID and that method work on the homepage just fine, but if go to any other page, those links doesnt work

Comment: I see an error on console when we click on that link, get rid of it. It's due to the click listener/binding in scrolling.js. Get rid of it.

Comment: i owe you a chocolate @sudhansuChoudhary it works

Comment: Cool.. thanks :) Check the console often when you run into issues.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary will do, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `/` before your URL

```
<a href="index.html#how-we-work">How we Work</a>
```

This `/` is going to the root of your folder. I guess your using relative path, so this should fix the issue.

Comment: The page on which is this link is in the same folder as your index.html ?

Comment: Index.html and tracking.html is on the same folder

Comment: What this is very weird because I created a index.html with this code in it : <div style="margin-top : 1800px; background-color : red;" id="how-to-work"><p>div</p></div> and another page tracking.html with your code, and it works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

In your webpage you have this code within "tracking.html":

```
<h2>About Us</h2>
<ul class="discover triangle hover row">
  <li class="col-xs-12"><a href="#">About EvisaXpress</a></li>
  <li class="col-xs-12"><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
  <li class="col-xs-12"><a href="#how-we-work">How We Work</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is linking to the current page, i.e. "tracking.html". Write instead

```
<a href="index.html#how-we-work">How We Work</a>
```

and you should be fine.

The difference is that in your page this is called:

http://evisax.com/tracking.html#how-we-work

whereas this is what you want to call:

http://evisax.com/index.html#how-we-work

Comment: but that code is on the footer not in the header on the tracking.html page

Answer (score 0):

Removing scrolling.js from the Tracking.html file and everything works fine.